# Is it too soon to use Couchbase Mobile?

Tags: iphone, ios, nosql, couchdb, couchbase

For an iPhone App I decided to give a try to a NoSQL DB, because the nature of the data I need to store locally. The most sophisticated solution I found is [Couchbase Mobile](http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/mobile-couchbase). But it seems, that [the project has only beta status](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/iOS-Couchbase). Is it too soon to use it?

Comment: This seems to be too localized in time, because you're asking about the condition of something right now.  Also, whether or not a project is ready to use would seem to be a subjective decision, because what's appropriate for one person may not be for another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couchbase Mobile is currently beta, with plans for a GA/1.0 at the end of September (2011).

By the next developer preview release at the end of August the iOS version should be entirely ready for you to start development with. The Android version is lagging a little in terms of documentation, but should also be ready for active development at the end of August.

If you are hard core, you can start today, but if you wait a few weeks we'll be ready for even the non-hardcore.

Comment: That's good news. Do you know whether the Apache license will remain for the end product?